# How to Handle multiple click listeners in a listView

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is my Adapter code:

```
 package com.app.beautysaloon;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.app.beautysaloon.Models.Orders;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.*;


public class CheckOutAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Orders> {

    int Current_quantity;
    int updated_quantity;
    List<Orders> i_List;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context123;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public CheckOutAdapter(Context context, List<Orders>Orders ) {


        super(context, R.layout.checkout_screen_for_addition,Orders
        );
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        context123 = context;
        i_List = Orders;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView item_name, item_quantity, item_description, item_price;
        Button add_btn, subtract_btn;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context123);
            convertView = inflater.inflate
                    (R.layout.checkout_screen_for_addition, null);
        }

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.item_name_tv);
        holder.item_quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.item_quantity_tv);
        holder.item_description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.description_tv_edt);
        holder.item_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.price_tv_edt);
        holder.add_btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.add_btn);
        holder.subtract_btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.subtract_btn);

        holder.item_name.setText(i_List.get(position).getItem_name());
        holder.item_quantity.setText(""+i_List.get(position).getItem_quantity());
        holder.item_description.setText(i_List.get(position).getItem_description());
        holder.item_price.setText("Rs." + i_List.get(position).getItem_price());

        holder.add_btn.setOnClickListener();

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**How Can, I make onclicklistners of my two buttons which are in my custom layout**

That is my custom layout XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/product_round_corners"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="7dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_name_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:text="Shoes"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/ProductFont"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/subtract_btn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.8"
                    android:background="@drawable/checkout_btn"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_quantity_tv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.8"
                    android:background="@drawable/product_round_corners"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/descriptionfont"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/add_btn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.8"
                    android:background="@drawable/checkout_btn"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description_tv_edt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:text="The Description about Shoes"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/descriptionfont"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/company_name_tv_edt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/price_tv_edt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:text="Rs 1200"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image: That is my custom layout image, I want to make on click listener of every button of "+" and "-" in every item of listview.]

That is my custom layout image, I want to make on click listener of every button of "+" and "-" in every item of the listview.

Please help me, I am very Thankful to you.

Comment: set separate `setOnClickListener` for each button

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as below:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context123);
            convertView = inflater.inflate
                    (R.layout.checkout_screen_for_addition, null);
        }

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.item_name_tv);
        holder.item_quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.item_quantity_tv);
        holder.item_description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.description_tv_edt);
        holder.item_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.price_tv_edt);
        holder.add_btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.add_btn);
        holder.subtract_btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.subtract_btn);

        holder.item_name.setText(i_List.get(position).getItem_name());
        holder.item_quantity.setText(""+i_List.get(position).getItem_quantity());
        holder.item_description.setText(i_List.get(position).getItem_description());
        holder.item_price.setText("Rs." + i_List.get(position).getItem_price());

        holder.add_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
               //your code here 
            }
        });

        holder.subtract_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //your code here

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

I am assuming you just need operations done using that buttons which can be done in the onclicklistner.

Comment: Akshay I also want to change the text view of the layout after clicking on these buttons. That text view which is in the middle of this button when I click "-" than the current no. will be subtracted 1 when I click"+" the current no. will be added with 1

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in the onCrate Method

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subtract_btn);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Subtracting code
         }
     });

final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             //Adding Code
         }
     });
```

Comment: seriously in OnCreate Method?

Answer (score 0):

Add this Code for handling click :

```
holder.add_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
               //your code here 
            }
        });

        holder.subtract_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //your code here

            }
        });
```

But if you want to maintain its value You can set tag to that view like this :

```
holder.add_btn.setTag(R.string.tag_one,item_quantity_tv.getText());
holder.add_btn.setTag(R.string.tag_two,item_quantity_tv);
```

And you can use it like this in click listner :

```
    holder.add_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                   int iVal=(int)v.getTag(R.string.tag_one);
                   iVal++;
                   TextView txtvwVal=(TextView )v.getTag(R.string.tag_two);
                   txtvwVal.setText(iVal);
                   v.setTag(R.string.tag_one,iVal);
                }
            });

holder.subtract_btn.setTag(R.string.tag_one,item_quantity_tv.getText());
holder.subtract_btn.setTag(R.string.tag_two,item_quantity_tv);

holder.subtract_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                   int iVal=(int)v.getTag(R.string.tag_one);
                   iVal--;
                   TextView txtvwVal=(TextView )v.getTag(R.string.tag_two);
                   txtvwVal.setText(iVal);
                   v.setTag(R.string.tag_one,iVal);
                }
            });
```

This is just sample example to your problem if I got it correct.
Note :  Declare this in your string.xml

```
<string name="tag_one">1</string>
<string name="tag_two">2</string>
```

Comment: I also want to change the text view of the layout after clicking on these buttons. That text view which is in the middle of these buttons when I click "-" than the current no. will be subtracted 1 when I click"+" the current no. will be added with 1

Comment: by using your code my listview disappear and i don't get any type of error on my android monitor

Comment: try debugging if there is no any error or share me your whole code. or try this updated code

Comment: Thanx Can you please provide me your skype id where i will directly share my code with you....

Comment: can you please update your code in your question... so that i could help you

Comment: Thanks, Apurva it works but it just updates the value of each item one time after that it does nothing.

Means my current value is 5 when I click on Add button it changes it into 6 but when i click again it doesn't make an increment.

Comment: And when i scroll up the screen its also change the updated value with old value means 6 going to be again 5

Comment: Check out the answer I got it, Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 0):

First of all inflate your view only once in constructor. currently you are inflating your views every time instead of reusing like this

```
  public CheckOutAdapter(Context context, List<Orders>Orders ) {


    super(context, R.layout.checkout_screen_for_addition,Orders
    );
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    context123 = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    i_List = Orders;
}
```

then

```
holder.add_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            i_List.get(position).setItem_quantity() = i_List.get(position).getItem_quantity()+1;
            holder.item_quantity.setText(""+ quantity);
        }
    });

    holder.subtract_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
             i_List.get(position).setItem_quantity() = i_List.get(position).getItem_quantity()-1;
            holder.item_quantity.setText(""+ quantity);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanx It works but It also change the values of other items with them..

Comment: what you mean values of other items?

Comment: when i click on plus button of item 1 it changes the value of text view inside item 1 but it also change the value of text view in item 3 ...

Comment: Same issue i.e multiple items values changing?

Comment: Check out the answer I got it, Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 0):

set android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" for buttons
in your custom layout of adapter and than apply click listener for each button

Answer (score 0):

All above answer is right, here key is **notifyDataSetChanged()** method

```
holder.add_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
               String newValue =i_List.get(position).getItem_quantity()+1;
               holder.item_quantity.setText(""+newValue);
               i_List.get(position).setItem_quantity(newValue);
               notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        holder.subtract_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
               String newValue =i_List.get(position).getItem_quantity()-1;
               holder.item_quantity.setText(""+newValue);
               i_List.get(position).setItem_quantity(newValue);
               notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

**notifyDataSetChanged()** will refresh your adapter with new value

Comment: Thanx Sushant It works but it also changes the vlues of all text view with click of any one button...

Comment: notifyItemChanged() is only present in RecyclerView Adapter not in array adapter , if you really want that than customize your adpter like for that refer this - https://gist.github.com/passsy/f8eecc97c37e3de46176

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.app.beautysaloon;


import com.app.beautysaloon.Models.Orders;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.*;


public class CheckOutAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Orders> {


    List<Orders> i_List;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context123;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public CheckOutAdapter(Context context, List<Orders>Orders ) {


        super(context, R.layout.checkout_screen_for_addition,Orders
        );
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        context123 = context;
        i_List = Orders;


        context123 = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        i_List = Orders;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView item_name, item_quantity, item_description, item_price;
        Button add_btn, subtract_btn;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context123);
            convertView = inflater.inflate
                    (R.layout.checkout_screen_for_addition, null);
        }

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.item_name_tv);
        holder.item_quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.item_quantity_tv);
        holder.item_description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.description_tv_edt);
        holder.item_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.price_tv_edt);
        holder.add_btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.add_btn);
        holder.subtract_btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById
                (R.id.subtract_btn);

        holder.item_name.setText(i_List.get(position).getItem_name());
        holder.item_quantity.setText(""+i_List.get(position).getItem_quantity());
        holder.item_description.setText(i_List.get(position).getItem_description());
        holder.item_price.setText("Rs." + i_List.get(position).getItem_price());

        //Creating Click listner of every item
        holder.add_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position, holder.item_quantity,"+"));
        holder.subtract_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position, holder.item_quantity,"-"));

        return convertView;
    }

    //That is the class which use to change value on Item click listner.

    private class OnItemClickListener  implements  View.OnClickListener {

        private int mPosition;
        private TextView tv;
        String sin;

        OnItemClickListener(int position,TextView tvs,String sing){
            mPosition = position;
            tv=tvs;
            sin=sing;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int q= CheckOut.orders_list.get(mPosition).getItem_quantity();
            if(sin.equals("+")){
                q++;
            }else if(sin.equals("-")){
                q--;
            }
            CheckOut.orders_list.get(mPosition).setItem_quantity(q);
            tv.setText(""+q);

        }
    }
}
```